# What is a network tickle? And how to I go about sending one?

Tags: c++, android, sockets, networking, android-c2dm

What is a network tickle?  And how to I go about sending one?

Comment: [Similar to a nearly two-year-old post, including grammatical mistake?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/3fd2fefab84b710b?pli=1) That's weird.

Comment: actually i picked it from there only. It was not clear to me from that post

Comment: If there is something there you don't understand, please edit your question to ask about that bit.

Comment: Do you really think that you're likely to get better answers if you copy and paste exactly the same vague question? You may find [these guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) to be helpful.

Comment: A lot has changed these two years ... see the answer below. And I have retagged the question accordingly, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Comment: If so much has changed, and this is really such a great question, doesn't it deserve an answer that is more than a link to another site? Wouldn't it be helpful if you *explained* what a "network tickle" is, as the question asked? I assume that the asker already *Googled* the question herself, given that they found the other post.

Comment: and yet the original poster have not found this because it's utterly nontrivial to get from tickle to C2DM.